# What is the meaning of `secret 0` in Cisco config?

Tags: cisco

I've been reading about [this here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/800/hardware/installation/guide/800HIG/initalconfig.html) and found the following config in it.

What is the meaning of the following lines?

`privilege 15 secret 0`

```
Router#
Router#config t
Router(config)#
Router(config)#username username privilege 15 secret 0 password
```

Besides `15` and `0`, sometimes I found that different device is configured with different numbers. [E.g.](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/46548)

```
username cisco123 privilege 15 secret 4 1wLgDhbOLsU0GdsP0B9e5YU2KA7gxZujqOLWf0j48q6
```

Also, I would like to know the full list of `privilege x secret x`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Privilege

The privilege number represents the level of access:

- **Level 15** is full administrator access
- **Level 1** is read only, with minimal access.

Other levels don't exist by default, but you can define custom access levels yourself. Read [this post on the Cisco Learning Network](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/docs/DOC-15878) for details.

### Secrets

The secret number represents the hashing algorithm type, which the IOS software uses obscure the secret password in the config:

- **Type 0** means plain text. In general, you only use this while entering the secret on the CLI, IOS will hash this for you.
- **Type 5** is MD5 hashed. This used to be the standard in IOS, but it might be vulnerable to a brute force attack so it's been replaced with more modern algorithms (type 8 and 9)
- **Type 7** is used in older kit. It's a [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher), so it is [easily reversed](https://packetlife.net/toolbox/type7/).

For the full list of algorithms, check the [Cisco Learning Network](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/docs/DOC-27166).